# trace the column following the string column for given dataset

Tags: python, pandas

Looking for generic logic which can be applied to any dataset for finding the column which falls next to string column.

Problem:
Sum of first column and the column following the one with the string datatype = 5th column

```
{
[10, 20, 'tyh', 30], 
[66, 88, 'ltk', 99],
[41, 31, 'qed', 11]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
[10, 20, 'tyh', 30, 40], 
[66, 88, 'ltk', 99, 165],
[41, 31, 'qed', 11 , 52]
}
```

The logic should work for below df also

```
{
[111, 'tfy', 122, 133],
[167, 'elt', 187, 197],
[143, 'xqe', 132, 112]
}
```

expected output :

```
{
[111, 'tfy', 122, 133 , 244],
[167, 'elt', 187, 197 , 364],
[143, 'xqe', 132, 112, 255]
}
```

what I did so far:

```
data[4]= data[0]+data[3]
```

but this is hard coded and so wont work for second df.

Answer (score 1):

```
str_col_no = df.columns[df.dtypes==object][0]
df[4] = df[0] + df[str_col_no+1]
```